# Unity Dialogue code not typing out characters of dialogue lines one by one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code listed below is supposed to take one character from the line string array and add it to the text that is displayed onscreen one by one, waiting for seconds equal to the float textSpeed, but instead it just displays the lines in full immediately without waiting in-between adding characters. I'm assuming it's adding the characters correctly, as they are displaying correctly, but the textSpeed part isn't being implemented correctly. The rest of the code works find but I included it anyways, the method that has issues is "TypeLine".

Edit: I got the code from following a popular YouTube video so I know the code is supposed to work, I just have an error somewhere, or maybe a unity update broke it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI textComp;
    public string[] lines;
    public float textspeed;
    private int index;
    void Start()
    {
        textComp.text = string.Empty;
        startDialogue();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
            {
            if (textComp.text == lines[index]) 
                {
                NextLine();
                }
            } else 
                { 
                    StopAllCoroutines(); 
                    textComp.text = lines[index];
                }
    }

    void startDialogue()
    {
        index = 0;
        StartCoroutine(TypeLine());
        
    }

    IEnumerator TypeLine()
    {
        
        //type each character 1 by 1
        foreach (char c in lines[index].ToCharArray())
        {
            textComp.text += c;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(textspeed);
        }
    
    }
    void NextLine()
    { 
    if (index < lines.Length - 1)
        {
            index++;
            textComp.text = string.Empty;
            StartCoroutine (TypeLine());
        }
    else
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like as long as you hold the mouse button down, you're going to call NextLine. So unless you can hold the button down for a single frame, you're going to get more than one character printed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this, but this is probably closer to what you are wanting:

```
public TextMeshProUGUI textComp;
public string[] lines;
public float textspeed;
private int index;

private bool isPrinting;

void Start()
{
    textComp.text = string.Empty;
    startDialogue();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
        if (textComp.text == lines[index]) 
        {
            if (!isPrinting)
            {
                isPrinting = true;
                NextLine();
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    { 
        if (isPrinting)
        {
            StopAllCoroutines(); 
            isPrinting = false;
            textComp.text = lines[index];
            index++;
        }
    }
}

void startDialogue()
{
    index = 0;
    StartCoroutine(TypeLine()); 
}

IEnumerator TypeLine()
{
    
    //type each character 1 by 1
    char[] chars = lines[index].ToCharArray();
    
    foreach (char c in chars)
    {
        textComp.text += c;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(textspeed);
    }
    index++;
    isPrinting = false;
}

void NextLine()
{ 
    if (index < lines.Length)
    {
        textComp.text = string.Empty;
        StartCoroutine (TypeLine());
    }
    else
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked to fix the first issue, though it did break the 'click to skip' feature in the update method. Ill try to fix that myself.